# Increase the size of elements in a @ElementCollection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have an `@Entity` in JPA which has a `@ElementCollection` like this:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
List<String> photodescription = new ArrayList<>();
```

The problem is that by default, the Column for any `photodescription` is a `VARCHAR(255)`.
I need to increase that to 10000.

Exists any anotation for the elements from a `@ElementCollection` to set a maximum size like `@Size(max=1000)` which is used for a simple String?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`@Column`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation should still work for this collection of strings:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(length=10000) // OR @Column(columnDefinition="VARCHAR(10000)")
List<String> photodescription = new ArrayList<>();
```